# Should we document AJAX-callback parameters?

Tags: 8, hooks, ajax

Considering the `PHPCS` warning:

> phpcs: Hook implementations should not duplicate @param documentation

Is there any way to tell *PHPCS* that the function is an AJAX-callback (so that such warnings are generated)?

Or, Should we document all AJAX-callback parameters, with `@param` PHPDoc?

---

#### Background:

There was a discussion in our company about the below AJAX-callback function:

```php
/**
 * Prevents popup's redirection from dashboard to another link.
 *
 * Users were redirected to another page as soon as the Event-creation
 * popup form was submitted, just added an AJAX handler to submit button
 * which prevents the redirect using ajax,
 * and when there is any error on the form, the message is sent to the popup.
 */
function _MYMODULE_popup_submit(array &$form, FormStateInterface $formState) {
  // ...
}
```

Where one developer insisted on adding `@param` PHPDoc comments to each AJAX-callback like:

```php
/**
 * Prevents popup's redirection from dashboard to another link.
 *
 * Users were redirected to another page as soon as the Event-creation
 * popup form was submitted, just added an AJAX handler to submit button
 * which prevents the redirection using ajax,
 * and when there is any error on the form, the message is sent to the popup.
 *
 * @param array &$form
 *   All data of the form.
 * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $formState
 *   State of the form.
 *
 * @return \Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse
 *   Returns the data back as AjaxResponse object.
 */
function _amt_dayview_popup_submit(array &$form, FormStateInterface $formState) {
  // ...
}
```

And the other considered it as understandable and that it should not be documented:

> ... remember that *PHPCS* will warn you every time we use `@param` on any hook, like "`phpcs: Hook implementations should not duplicate @param documentation`", and just because *PHPCS* can not differ AJAX-callback from normal functions it does not mean that we should do this ...

---

**Edit:** The feature request is created for this on [Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/3074811).

Comment: Custom functions and code that have custom functionality like this should be commented like above. Six months from now no one will remember what it does or why, or that it’s specifically for an AJAX callback. As for the params, these are pretty standard for a form submit hook. They aren’t necessary here really, but most editors will just add it automatically. Verbose yes, but doesn’t hurt much. Perhaps you hire new dev interns someday - it’s helpful downstream.

Comment: @Kevin, I found the docs about [Callback definitions and implementation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/standards/api-documentation-and-comment-standards#callback-def) (which suggests "`Implements callback_descriptive_name`"),  but the problem now is that there was nothing like `callback_form_ajax` in any `*.api.php` file !!

Comment: Is "`./modules/custom/MYMODULE\MYMODULE.api.php`" the right place for our own custom callback definitions? because *PHPCS* doesn't seem to recognize any of them.

Comment: Just checked and *PHPCS* even ignores "`Implements callback_batch_finished`" (which is in the "`./core/lib/Drupal/Core/Form/form.api.php`" file), so, this feature seems to be not yet supported by *PHPCS* for now.

Comment: This is not a hook implementation in the sense intended by the documentation. That's only for MYMODULE_name_of_hook or MYTHEME_name_of_hook functions. So if you write an implementation of hook_entity_access, for example, you do not document its parameters.

Comment: Callbacks are not hook implementations, even though their parameters are documented somewhere else. And they do not belong in your api.php file.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong, Please read the docs which I [linked above](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/standards/api-documentation-and-comment-standards#callback-def), you will see they are clearly about **`callback`** (not hook, although they are near each other), and of course, they do not belong in my personal `*.api.php` file, but that is just a workaround to prevent copy/paste until Drupal's own `*.api.php` files are more complete.

Comment: OK, take your point.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to tell PHPCS that the function is an AJAX-callback (so that such warnings are generated)?

Yes, it's as simple as implementing hooks except that instead of "`Implements hook_`", it starts with "`Implements callback_`".

The only problem is that currently (August 2019) it is not supported by Drupal's *PHPCS* standard and you don't get any warnings yet.

> Or, Should we document all AJAX-callback parameters, with @param PHPDoc?

That too is an option, for your newly hired dev interns, but especially when there was no official definition in any existing `*.api.php` file and when you do not want to write your own `*.api.php` file.

#### Source:

In Drupal's [Official-documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/standards/api-documentation-and-comment-standards#callback-def) of August 2019, we can find below *Callback implementation*:

```php
/**
 * Implements callback_batch_finished().
 */
function _node_mass_update_batch_finished($success, $results, $operations) {
  // …
}
```

> **Note:** Unlike hooks any callback starts with an underscore (i.e. it is "`_MYMODULE_descreptive_name`").

---

#### Callback definition example:

In our case, because Drupal's own `*.api.php` files did not cover AJAX-callbacks, we added our own `*.api.php` file to prevent copy/paste until Drupal's own `*.api.php` files cover that section as well, something like below:

```php
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Callbacks and hooks related to MYPROJECT system.
 */

/**
 * @addtogroup callbacks
 * @{
 */

use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\HtmlCommand;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Callback for AJAX events.
 *
 * AJAX callback functions can be used to update existing or
 * add new form fields, update values in form fields and more,
 * while users can still interact with the form.
 *
 * @param array &$form
 *   All data of the form.
 * @param \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $formState
 *   State of the form.
 *
 * @return \Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse
 *   Returns the data back as AjaxResponse object.
 */
function callback_form_ajax(array &$form, FormStateInterface $formState) {
  // Here we do something meaningful with the results.
  $response = new AjaxResponse();
  $response->addCommand(new HtmlCommand('#message-box', 'my message.'));
  return $response;
}

/**
 * @} End of "addtogroup callbacks".
 */

/**
 * @addtogroup hooks
 * @{
 */

/* Place any hook definitions here. */

/**
 * @} End of "addtogroup hooks"
 */
```

#### Callback implementation example:

```php
/**
 * Implements callback_form_ajax().
 *
 * Prevents popup's redirection from dashboard to another link.
 *
 * Users were redirected to another page as soon as the Event-creation
 * popup form was submitted, just added an AJAX handler to submit button.
 * which prevents the redirect using ajax,
 * and when there is any error on the form, the message is sent to the popup.
 */
function _amt_dayview_popup_submit(array &$form, FormStateInterface $formState) {
  // ...
}
```